# qt4 not loaded odbc drivers

Tags: c++, qt4, odbc

I created new application with QtSDK (latest available version) and this programs use odbc for database connection, but when I try add database I got error:

```
QSqlDatabase: QODBC driver not loaded
QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE
```

When I do:

```
QStringList driversList = QSqlDatabase::drivers();
qDebug() << "drivers list= " << driversList;
```

I says that I have only qsqlite in list.
After first time get this error, I remembered that on this computer I didn't build odbc plugin, so I went to plugins and did "qmake; name". After that I got qsqlodbc4.dll and "qsqlodbc.intermediate.manifest"

So it was a surprise when I created "sqldrivers" folder in same folder as .exe, copied these 2 odbc files there and still got same error.
Program created with QtCreator and have same drivers list (qsqlite) when run from there and directly exe.
Anyone can sugest where to look next?

When I look at process list I can see that this program runs as 32bit ("program.exe *32"). And windows is 64, maybe there's some issue with loading?

Comment: When starting from QtCreator: Starting D:\Projects\Program\Program-build-simulator-Simulator_Qt_for_Visual_Studio_2005__Qt_SDK__Release\release\Program.exe (just in case it could help)

Comment: When copy program.exe (qt dll's and sqldrivers/qsqlodbc4.dll) to flash driver and run from there getting same drivers list (qsqlite), but if I try run it on other computer, I got empty drivers list. For me that looks like it try load from some special folder and not current program folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstalled all QtSDK, installed again only 4.7.4 version with MS Visual Studio 2005 (source and desktop). 
Build sql drivers and now they work.
My ques would be that when I compiled first time, there was few different version and drivers was build bad (somehow), therefore they did not load.

Answer (score 0):

i not familiar with odbc but i have related problem with mysql when forgot show to Qt lib_mysql.lib

Comment: I saw that this was basic problem with mysql drivers, but I didn't read anywhere about any special odbc libs. And can't remember any special libs when created similar program with Qt3 and odbc.

Comment: are you have `%QTDIR%\plugins\sqldrivers\qsqlodbc4.dll` ?  first this dll for Release version, are you using same; second have you load QtSql4.dll?

Comment: Both Yes. And when QtSql4.dll is missing program shows error very early. I even tried QTPLUGIN += qsqlodbc4 and put qsqlodbc4.lib (and exp) file to lib folder, but drivers list still same.

Comment: try to place `QtSql4.dll` and `plugins\sqldrivers\qsqlodbc4.dll` into directory with your application